# Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Using spring cloud stream, encounter the following problem:

Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]

my spring cloud steam dependencies is judged by

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Brooklyn.SR1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: fixed it.  Put your application class annotated with @SpringBootApplicatio into package.

Comment: I had the similar problem even when the classes were inside a package. I fixed the problem by deleting the `out` directory from gradle build in which there was class file for which the source file had already been deleted resulting the conflict.

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting scenario, hence posting @unixnothing 's comment as Community wiki answer.

This happens when your application class is defined in base package (in other words, without package declaration)

Move your classes to a package to avoid such name conflicts.

Please refer to [The Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-the-default-package) for more details.